# How do you put a BufferedImage into a ByteBuffer?

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage, bytebuffer

I have a BufferedImage, but I need to make it into a ByteBuffer so I can apply it to a CubeMap face.

Comment: I don't know about the Bufferedimage part but here is a tutorial to load a ByteBuffer into a cubemap: http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jogl/how-to-use-cube-map-textures.html

Comment: Please take a look at Harald's response to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29301838/converting-bufferedimage-to-bytebuffer

Answer (score 0):

Create a byte[] from the BufferedImage that you can put into the ByteBuffer.

Example to create a byte[] can be found here:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-bufferedimage-to-byte-in-java/